# How to provide the "result.has_errors()" and "result.has_validation_errors()" attributes when using import_data method for Django import_export

Tags: django-import-export

I need to make changes to a csv file being imported using the module `import_Export` for Django. I implement the `import_data` method for this but get the error `'Dataset' object has no attribute 'has_errors'`

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 231, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\import_export\admin.py", line 316, in import_action
    if not result.has_errors() and not result.has_validation_errors():

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/engine/mtg/import/
Exception Value: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'has_errors'
```

How can I provide the `result.has_error()` and `result.has_validation_errors()` when I return my customized dataset to avoid this error? Here is where I implement the method

> Admin

```
    class ModelResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def import_data(self, dataset, dry_run=False, raise_errors=True,use_transactions=None, collect_failed_rows=False, **kwargs):
        new_dataset = do_stuff(dataset)
        return new_dataset
```

The documentation states that the first thing that the `import_data` method does is create a "result" instance containing error information. I'm assuming this is what I need maybe? But I don't know how to gain access to it or return it with my new dataset[Import Data workflow][1]

[1]: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import_workflow.html?highlight=before)import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to override `has_errors()` and `has_validation_errors()` because the logic should be handled for you.

Generally you shouldn't be over-riding `import_data()` because this is where the import logic happens.  Pass a valid `Dataset` object into `import_data()` as the first arg.  I suggest having a quick look at the [source](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L594), because this will clarify what is going on.

If you need to modify the imported data, then there are several hooks you can use.  This is where you subclass the base Resource and add your own logic.

This example is based on the django-import-export [example app](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#example-app):

```py
class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):
    
    def before_import_row(self, row, row_number=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Override to add additional logic.
        """
        pass

    def before_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
        """
        Override to add additional logic.
        """
        pass

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'author_email', 'price')
```

Then you can call this with:

```py
    rows = [
        ('book1', 'email@example.com', '10.25'),
        ('book2', 'email@example.com', '10.25'),
        ('book1', 'email@example.com', '10.25'),
    ]
    dataset = tablib.Dataset(*rows, headers=['name', 'author_email', 'price'])

    book_resource = BookResource()
    result = book_resource.import_data(dataset)
    print(result.totals)
```